# How to get a coverage report for the file under test?

Tags: dart, code-coverage

I'm trying to get the coverage report for the file under test, but I'm failing.

I created a new Dart library project called FooBar with the following files:

```
FooBar/
├── lib
│   ├── FooBar.dart
│   └── src
│       └── FooBar_base.dart
└── test
    └── FooBar_test.dart
```

To generate the coverage report I call `dart --pause-isolates-on-exit --enable-vm-service=47114 test/FooBar_test.dart` and on another console I call `pub global run coverage:collect_coverage --uri=http://127.0.0.1:47114/ -o coverage.json --resume-isolates`.

With this two commands, I get a huge JSON file.

The `coverage` package has a formatter too. So I call `pub global run coverage:format_coverage -i coverage.json`. I get a nice formatted output but of the wrong file. It prints the test file but not the file under test.

```
$ pub global run coverage:format_coverage -i coverage.json
/Users/ralphbergmann/development/dart/FooBar/test/FooBar_test.dart
       |import 'package:FooBar/FooBar.dart';
       |import 'package:test/test.dart';
       |
      1|void main() {
      2|  group('A group of tests', () {
       |    Awesome awesome;
       |
      2|    setUp(() {
      1|      awesome = new Awesome();
       |    });
       |
      2|    test('First Test', () {
      2|      expect(awesome.isAwesome, isTrue);
       |    });
       |  });
       |}
```

How do I get a formatted report about the file under test? I know there are some options for the `coverage:format_coverage` command, but they didn't solve my problem. For example, I added the `--packages=.packages` option with the result that I get a formatted report for all Dart files and not only for my own.

Comment: You need 3rd party tools get formatted output.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `format_coverage` collects coverage for the full transitive closure of imported Dart sources. To restrict reporting to a specific subset of files, it supports a `--report-on` option.

The `--report-on` option filters based on the resolved absolute path of the sources. In your case, passing `--report-on=/Users/ralphbergmann/development/dart/FooBar/lib` should restrict coverage collection to that directory.

Comment: I should note that it seems reasonable for us to make this the default when the option isn't specified, please feel free to [file this](https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage/issues) as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

I use this script for Dart coverage:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p ./coverage

dart run test --coverage=./coverage

format_coverage --packages=.packages --report-on=lib --report-on=example --report-on=bin -l -o ./coverage/lcov.info -i ./coverage

genhtml -o ./coverage ./coverage/lcov.info

open ./coverage/index.html
```

Maybe you need to activate `format_coverage`:

`dart pub global activate coverage`